# Partition function of fermions with spin

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, partition-function

How do you write the partition function of fermions that can have spin 1/2 and spin -1/2, in a system with N states. I know fermions with the same spin cant occupy the same state, but how do I translate that into the partition function?

Comment: The partition function depends on the Hamiltonian. Do you mean non-interacting fermions? How does the Hamiltonian look like? Additionally, how many fermions do you consider?

Comment: it is non interacting fermions and the  number of fermions is 5. and you can consider the energy associated of a harmonic oscillator. I cant understand how the summation is made.

Comment: You should consider to include these things in the question. Moreover, you should include most of the calculations that you've performed so far.

Comment: this isnt a problem that i found, I was solving a problem with 2 bosons with spin 0 and got me thinking how would I do solve the problem if it was fermions. I didnt perform the calculations, because I really dont how to approach the situation. I thought maybe perform a product of five summations, for each particle, but I still dont know how to solve the fact that there spin 1/2 and -1/2.